# Can http4s do different status codes given a Future?

Tags: scala, task, future, http4s

I'm using [http4s](http://http4s.org/), and I have a `Try` that generates some json data for a response:

```
case GET -> Root / "something" =>
   getSomethingTry() match {
    case Success(something) => Ok(something)
    case Failure(CustomNotFoundException(reason)) => NotFound(reason)
    case Failure(CustomConflictException()) => Conflict()
   }
```

This function correctly returns a `Task[Response]`

However, I want to replace the `Try` with a `Future`. Matching no longer works, because the future may not have been resolved at the time of the match. So, I can map the future:

```
case GET -> Root / "something" =>
   getSomethingFuture().map {
    something => Ok(something)
   }.recover {
    case CustomNotFoundException(reason) => NotFound(reason)
    case CustomConflictException() => Conflict()
   }
```

But this returns a `Future[Task[Response]]` which is not what http4s wants. It doesn't seem appropriate to use `Await.result` to unbox the `Future` - I think this could cause thread pool issues - but it does make the code work.

http4s accepts futures as the argument to the task creator:

```
case GET -> Root / "something" =>
   Ok(getSomethingFuture())
```

But this doesn't let me set different status codes in the event of different errors. A solution could be to do a `.recover` on a task, but I can't see an obvious way to do that.

How can I call different http4s task wrappers in the event of different `Future` failure cases? Do I need to use middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `http4s` 0.17 and higher, your `Task` is `fs2.Task`.

It's easy to convert the `Future` to `Task` and then deal with the latter:

```
case GET -> Root / "something" =>
   Task.fromFuture(getSomethingFuture())
     .flatMap {
       something => Ok(something)
     }
     .handleWith {
       case CustomNotFoundException(reason) => NotFound(reason)
       case CustomConflictException() => Conflict()
     }
```

I'd recommend, however, to use `Task` throughout your program instead of `Try` or `Future`

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. Trying this code says I need an implicit `Strategy` - is there any reason I shouldn't do: `implicit val strategy = Strategy.fromCachedDaemonPool()`?

Comment: @TimothyJones you can do that. I prefer using the default of standard `Future` - `Strategy.fromExecutionContext(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global)`, but you can always fine-tune it later (just don't create a new strategy for every service :)

Comment: Thanks! The version of `fs2` that we have doesn't have a default, so I needed to provide one.

Answer (score -2):

You dont really need to unwrap the future. Play framework provides action.async for returning Future.

You can use it in the following way

```
Action.async {
  getSomethingFuture().map {
    something => Ok(something)
   }.recover {
    case CustomNotFoundException(reason) => NotFound(reason)
    case CustomConflictException() => Conflict()
   }
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync#returning-futures

Comment: http4s is not Play.

Comment: I agree with Oleg- this produces an `Action`, which isn't appropriate at this point (and the helpers for `Ok()` etc also don't have the correct type)